# Counting issue wth Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counting

So I'm trying to count unique letter in this function. If their are unique letters return True if there isn't return False. In the word 'Programming'
there are two r's and two m's and two g's. Its return True where the actual answer is False? Is my logic wrong here?

```
def unique_chars_in_string(input_string):
    unique_chars = {}
    if input_string == "":
        return True

    for letter in input_string:
        if letter in unique_chars:
            unique_chars[letter]+=1
        else:
             unique_chars[letter]=1


    for k in unique_chars:
        if unique_chars[k] > 1:
            return False

        else:
            return True


print(unique_chars_in_string('Programming'))
```

Comment: problem is returning True as soon as some letter isn't there many times... Try with `PProgramming`...

Comment: `return all(k == 1 for k in unique_chars.values())`

Answer (score 1):

According to your algorithm, you're just checking the first character of the string. And not the entire string.

This block of code has erroneus logic:

```
for k in unique_chars:
    if unique_chars[k] > 1:
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

You don't need that else condition inside the `for` loop.

Try this instead:

```
def unique_chars_in_string(input_string):
    unique_chars = {}
    if input_string == "":
        return True

    for letter in input_string:
        if letter in unique_chars:
            unique_chars[letter]+=1
        else:
             unique_chars[letter]=1


    for k in unique_chars:
        if unique_chars[k] > 1:
            return False

    return True


print(unique_chars_in_string('Programming'))
```

So, if any character has more than `1` count, your code will return `false` else it will return `true`.

> Also, check [`Jean-François Fabre's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502602/8489276) to this problem, it is a short and sweet Pythonic implementation.

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if all letters occur only once use `all`

```
return all(k == 1 for k in unique_chars.values())
```

that will avoid to return too soon a result when you haven't scanned the rest of the letters.

Also consider counting your letters with `collections.Counter` which is a specialized dictionary made for counting hashable elements:

```
unique_chars = collections.Counter(input_string)
```

so combining in one line:

```
return all(k == 1 for k in collections.Counter(input_string).values())
```

That said, we're *missing* the point. If we need to check if a word has non-duplicate letters this can be done without counting using a `set`:

```
return len(input_string) == len(set(input_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You return too early in the loop when you encounter the first unique character. You only know all are unique at the end of the loop:

```
def unique_chars_in_string(input_string):
    unique_chars = {}
    for letter in input_string:
        if letter in unique_chars:
            unique_chars[letter]+=1
        else:
             unique_chars[letter]=1

    for k in unique_chars:
        if unique_chars[k] > 1:
            return False  # not all are unique -> return early
    # but only when all have been checked, can you know for sure all are
    return True
```

This whole function can be shortened, using `collections.Counter` and `all`, but maintaining the underlying algorithm:

```
from collections import Counter

def unique_chars_in_string(input_string):
    return all(v==1 for v in Counter(input_string).values())
```

Or even simpler:

```
def unique_chars_in_string(input_string):
    return len(input_string) == len(set(input_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in unique_chars:
    if unique_chars[k] > 1:
        return False

    else:
        return True
```

This is your problem. This checks if *any* value in `unique_chars` is greater than one, *or* if the **first** value is one or less. You should instead do:

```
for k in unique_chars:
    if unique_chars[k] > 1:
        return False
return True  # since this is after the for loop, it only runs if
             # no character has a count greater than one.
```

Alternatively this can be made more efficient with a `set`.

```
seen = set()
for c in input_string:
    if c in seen:
        return False
    seen.add(c)
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Programming'

a = [True for i in s if s.count(i) > 1]
if any(a):
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre nope, it checks the entire thing for doubles and then tests the results, are you saying a better design would stop as soon as a double is encountered, if so I agree that would save resources

Comment: yes `any(s.count(i) > 1 for i in s)` which is the exact opposite of my initial comment about `all`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are also assuming I read your comments, I did not, I just seen and answered, but I agree your methods are more efficient and OP should use them, just offering my approach to the problem